# PHP class method arguments without dollar symbol ($)

Tags: php, class, methods, arguments

On the [PHP: Object Interface Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) the following is an excerpt from one of the examples:

```
class c implements b
{
    public function foo()
    {
    }

    public function baz(Baz $baz)
    {
    }
}
```

In the public function baz, the arguments are Baz $baz. I am unfamiliar with this form of syntax for a method. Is it valid and if so what does it do?

Comment: This is known as [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

public function baz( Baz $baz )

means the variable of $baz must be an object of the class Baz

for example

```
$baz = new Baz();

$c = new C();

$c->baz( $baz ); // valid
$c->baz( 'hello' ); // error
```